# Extract the inline style in html body tag using preg_match

Tags: php

I want to extract a string included in the html `body` tag.

example input :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
         <body style="color:red" >
           hello
           <p>test</p>
           <div>how r u</div>
         </body>
    </html>
```

output :

```
style="color:red"
```

I need the content at first occurance of  `>`

i used this /body(.*)>/ in preg_match

Comment: feel free to show us what you have tried yet

Comment: Something like this: `style="(.*)"`. Post what you have tried by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/style="(.*?)"/is',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
$html = '<html>
    <head></head>
    <body class="home blog" style="color:red;">
        example
        <p> test </p>
    </body>
';

$tes = preg_match('/\<body(.*?)\>/', $html, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

will output

```
class="home blog" style="color:red;"
```

Comment: thanks @park
but my html will be
$html = '<html>
    <head></head>
    <body class="home blog" style="color:red;">
        example
        <p> test </p>
    </body>
';

in this case i got 

$html = '<html>
    <head></head>
    <body class="home blog" style="color:red;">
        example
    </body>
';

Comment: I have edit my answer, I forget to add **?** on **(.*)**